# Is it possible to use array_merge_recursive without assoc keys?

Tags: php

Given that I have the request data below:

```
$request = [
    'name' => ['John Doe', 'Jane Doe', 'Janie Doe'],
    'email' => ['john@doe.com', 'jane@doe.com', 'janie@doe.com'],
    'password' => ['john123', 'jane123', 'janie123'],
];
```

I want to make it look like this:

```
array:3 [▼
  0 => array:3 [▼
    0 => "John Doe"
    1 => "john@doe.com"
    2 => "john123"
  ]
  1 => array:3 [▼
    0 => "Jane Doe"
    1 => "jane@doe.com"
    2 => "jane123"
  ]
  2 => array:3 [▼
    0 => "Janie Doe"
    1 => "janie@doe.com"
    2 => "janie123"
  ]
]
```

When I use array_merge_recursive();

```
$result = array_merge_recursive($request['name'], $request['email'], $request['password']);
```

The `$result` looks like this.

```
array:9 [▼
  0 => "John Doe"
  1 => "Jane Doe"
  2 => "Janie Doe"
  3 => "john@doe.com"
  4 => "jane@doe.com"
  5 => "janie@doe.com"
  6 => "john123"
  7 => "jane123"
  8 => "janie123"
]
```

However, when I add a prefix to all of my values like so:

```
$request = [
    'name' => [
        'user_0' => 'John Doe',
        'user_1' => 'Jane Doe',
        'user_2' => 'Janie Doe',
    ],
    'email' => [
        'user_0' => 'john@doe.com',
        'user_1' => 'jane@doe.com',
        'user_2' => 'janie@doe.com',
    ],
    'password' => [
        'user_0' => 'john123',
        'user_1' => 'jane123',
        'user_2' => 'janie123',
    ],
];
```

This same code below gives me a very different result.

```
$result = array_merge_recursive($request['name'], $request['email'], $request['password']);
```

Which looks like this:

```
array:3 [▼
  "user_0" => array:3 [▼
    0 => "John Doe"
    1 => "john@doe.com"
    2 => "john123"
  ]
  "user_1" => array:3 [▼
    0 => "Jane Doe"
    1 => "jane@doe.com"
    2 => "jane123"
  ]
  "user_2" => array:3 [▼
    0 => "Janie Doe"
    1 => "janie@doe.com"
    2 => "janie123"
  ]
]
```

So, if I were to loop through my request and prefix the keys, I can simply use `array_merge_recursive()`. But then it's redundant since I am already looping my request values and can simply assign them to a hand made `$results` during the loop.

Is there a secret to make `array_merge_recursive()` just work as I want it to?

Answer (score 1):

Using `array_map()`, you can get it to combine the arrays if you pass in null as the callback, from the manual...

> NULL can be passed as a value to callback to perform a zip operation
> on multiple arrays. If only array1 is provided, array_map() will
> return the input array.

```
$result = array_map(null, $request['name'], $request['email'], $request['password']);
```